# What is the size of Skull Island in Kong:Skull Island (2017) movie?

Tags: geography, king-kong

Gargantuan apes once thrived on the island for millions of years, before they were almost wiped out by Skullcrawlers, except for Kong. These beasts coexisted with other bizarre and large lifeforms on Skull Island. So what is the size (area) of the island based on the map in the movie?

The size can be given in square kilometers, or it could also be said in reference to real world landforms (like the size of Texas, Sumatra etc).

Comment: [Skull island?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OwN7eYZseI)

Comment: The question of the size of the island (and its inability to support an ecosystem of giants) is addressed in the dupe. In short, the island is relatively small but represents the entrance to an underground world.

Comment: The other question does not directly ask about the area size of skull island. What I want to know the size estimate of the skull island (not the creatures) based on the map shown in the movie?

Answer (score 4):

Based on an eyeball analysis of the official [Skull Island](https://screenrant.com/kong-skull-island-nycc-poster-godzilla-connections/) poster (which helpfully includes a map scale at the bottom), the island is approximately 51 x 37 miles at its greatest extent. Approximately 60-70%(ish) of the island's area within those bounds is water, giving us an approx landmass of around 1000KM<sup>2</sup> or around the same as the small island nation of [Dominica.](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Dominica/@15.4263293,-61.4975913,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8c14d2faf2155a15:0x49b39109053afd3c!8m2!3d15.414999!4d-61.370976)

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you!! This is the answer that I was looking for!!!!

Comment: Does anyone know about the size of Skull Island in the 2005 version of the movie??

Comment: @Chipboy123 - For the record, that's a very answerable question if you want to ask it on the main site.